Is this Python/Pygame that draws a maze well structured?
I'm not very confident about this piece of code I created, it basically takes a file like this:
##    #
## ## #
#B #  #
# ## ##
     ##
A######

Then proceeds to draw a maze in the window.
The class Maze has 3 variables: columns, rows and maze_layout (a matrix each location is a character) example 2x2 maze: [["#" "A"],["#","B"]].
The code is this:
import pygame
import sys
import os

# Size of each square on the Maze
MAZE_SQUARESIZE = 40

# Colors
GREEN = (34, 139, 34)
ROSERED = (180, 75, 95)
DARKGRAY = (69, 69, 69)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
DARKPURPLE = (48, 25, 52)

    # Creates a Maze with pygame
    class Maze:
        def __init__(self, filename):
            if not os.path.isfile(filename):
                raise FileNotFoundError("File not found:", filename)
            with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                self.maze_layout = [list(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in file.readlines()]
                self.cols = len(self.maze_layout[0])
                self.rows = len(self.maze_layout)
        
        def display_maze(self, screen):
            self.draw_grid(screen)
            while True:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                pygame.display.update()
        
        # Drawing functions for maze
        def draw_grid(self, window):
            for x in range(self.rows):
                for y in range(self.cols):
                    rect = pygame.Rect(y * MAZE_SQUARESIZE, x * MAZE_SQUARESIZE, MAZE_SQUARESIZE, MAZE_SQUARESIZE)
                    if self.maze_layout[x][y] == "#":
                        pygame.draw.rect(window, DARKPURPLE, rect)
                    elif self.maze_layout[x][y] == " ":
                        pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, rect, 1)
                    elif self.maze_layout[x][y] == "A":
                        pygame.draw.rect(window, ROSERED, rect)
                    elif self.maze_layout[x][y] == "B":
                        pygame.draw.rect(window, GREEN, rect)
                    
    def main():
        pygame.init()
        filename = "maze1.txt"
        maze = Maze(filename)
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((maze.cols * MAZE_SQUARESIZE, maze.rows * MAZE_SQUARESIZE))
        maze.display_maze(screen)
        pygame.quit()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

If someone could find ways to improve this code, I would be very grateful.
I'm open to any sort of criticism.

line 17 class Maze: IndentationError: unexpected indent

The structure looks great.
In particular, each method is small, and its
single responsibility
is clear.
Also there's a nice __main__ guard,
so unit tests can safely import this module.
EAFP over LBYL
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise FileNotFoundError("File not found:", filename)
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:

In the python community we often say it's easier
to ask forgiveness than permission -- no need to look before you leap.
Just let the exception happen.
Here, we could delete the {if, raise} entirely,
since open() will raise if need be.
Strictly speaking, there is a race condition in the OP code;
after the .isfile() call succeeds,
the filesystem could still rm the file and the open fails.
Which makes us wonder if the "extra" check is helping at all.
And we've not even considered permission errors like
a root-owned text file that isn't world readable.
The diagnostic error message does not appear to be correctly formatted:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno File not found:] maze1.txt

You're passing in (str, str), but I think in the multiple-arg case
it wants (int, str).
anonymous parameter
    filename = "maze1.txt"
    maze = Maze(filename)

Given that we won't use that filespec again, we would usually just write
    maze = Maze("maze1.txt")

or
    maze = Maze(Path("maze1.txt"))

command line arg
Consider doing an import of
typer,
and then a signature of def main(filename):
or even def main(filename="maze1.txt"):
would offer convenient CLI access to multiple maze files.
pathlib
Use this module when you can.
It's more descriptive to pass in a Path than to pass in a str.
It's more convenient to ask if filename.exists():
than to rely on the ancient os.path module.
BTW, mode='r' is the default on open() and may be elided.
annotation
The identifiers we see in your Public API, such as filename
and screen, are terrific. They are very clear and self-explanatory.
But do consider spelling out the type, such as filename: Path.
Then the mypy
linter can help you with verifying that callers are passing
the right params in the right order.
And while you're linting, might as well run
black and
isort
over your code every now and again, plus the occasional
ruff check.
Kudos on offering those .cols and .rows attributes to the caller.
docstring
# Creates a Maze with pygame
class Maze:

Prefer to write that as a """docstring""" immediately after the class line.
Similarly for the draw_grid() comment.
performance
That while True: loop is burning more CPU cycles than necessary.
Simplest fix is to pause for 100 msec:
from time import sleep
...
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)
        ...

A more sophisticated approach would rely on
pygame.event.wait(),
as that lets us specify a suitable timeout value.
Standard idiom would be to use
Clock.tick(10)
if we want to sleep 100 msec
to ensure a window close event will soon be seen.
kwarg
This is perfectly nice as-is.
    pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, rect, 1)

But consider spelling out ..., rect, width=1)
for the benefit of the Gentle Reader who perhaps
hasn't memorized the order of that method's optional args.
mapping
We could DRY up
some of those repeated elifs with a dict:
grid_appearance = {
    "#": DARKPURPLE,
    " ": WHITE,
    "A": ROSERED,
    "B": GREEN,
}

We could add the width detail, as well, for retrieval with tuple unpack:
grid_appearance = {
    "#": (0, DARKPURPLE),
    " ": (1, WHITE),
    "A": (0, ROSERED),
    "B": (0, GREEN),
}
...
    for y ...
        rect = ...
        width, color = grid_appearance[self.maze_layout[x][y]]
        pygame.draw.rect(window, color, rect, width=width)


Inside class Maze you have:
def display_maze(self, screen):
    self.draw_grid(screen)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit() + sys.exit() are redundant.
A class or a package is stuff that is meant to be reused and that you import for a specific purpose, but it should stick to operating within its own scope. It shouldn't affect the execution flow of the upstream (caller) routine. It is not the responsibility of your class to exit the application.
It should be sufficient to rewrite your loop like:
while event != pygame.QUIT:
    ...

When the condition is met then the class will return and execution will resume inside the main block, where the very next statement is indeed pygame.quit() and this is the only one you need to have:
def main():
    pygame.init()
    filename = "maze1.txt"
    maze = Maze(filename)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((maze.cols * MAZE_SQUARESIZE, maze.rows * MAZE_SQUARESIZE))
    maze.display_maze(screen)
    pygame.quit()

Also, this can be simplified:
self.maze_layout = [list(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in file.readlines()]

Since readlines already returns a list of lines you can simply do:
self.maze_layout = file.readlines()

In case you need to run on a different environment like Windows that has different line endings, you would simply adapt the file open like this:
f = open(file,mode='r', encoding='utf8', newline='\r\n')


Overview
You've done a good job:

The code layout is good
You leveraged code written by others with the imports
Used meaningful names  for classes, functions and variables

Here are some adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.
Indentation
When I ran the code I copied from the question, I got a syntax error due to the
indentation of the class and the code that followed.  If I remove the indentation,
the code runs without a problem.  Either you had a problem posting the code
into the question, or the version of Python you used to run your code is
more forgiving than mine.
Documentation
Add docstrings for the class and functions.  These should briefly describe the purpose
of the code.
Unused code
Since these colors are not used, simplify the code by removing them:
DARKGRAY = (69, 69, 69)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

Lint check
pylint recommends moving the standard imports for
os and sys before import pygame.
Input checking
Consider adding some checking of the input file contents.
The code expects the following 4 characters: A, B, # and space.
For example, what should happen if the input file has the character C.
